# Using Arrays in PHP (for inexperienced programmer)

Tags: php, arrays

I have a javascript code that calculates and organizes some variables through multiple functions, however I was informed for this application my code needs to run on server side, therefore I need to rewrite in PHP. As someone who knows ***nothing*** about PHP, I was relieved when I saw that using if,for etc was just like JS.

However I am at complete loss about **how to use arrays in PHP.** The tutorials on internet are all  for html/PHP context, whereas I just want to have code that calculates some variables and store them in arrays before passing them on to database.

If someone would be kind enough to translate below JS code portion into PHP friendly version, then I can fix rest of my code based on that example.

example of what I have in JS:

```
var my_array[]; 
var my_multiarray[];
var i,o;

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    my_array[i]=i;

    for(o=0;o<5;o++){
        my_multiarray[i][o]=o;
}
```

Comment: You need php code for above?

Comment: Is seems you have not googled enough..

Comment: Here is not free code writing facility. Find a good tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I wish array handling tutorials for PHPs on the internet were better so I would not need to clutter here. And for the people who complained about me asking a question, I believe we have different cultural values. In mine it is not shameful not to know something, but it is shameful not to ask when you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$my_array = array(); //array declaration php 
$my_multiarray = array();
$i,$o; // this can also be declared directly in the loop php does not require predeclaration

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
$my_array[$i]=$i;

for($o=0;$o<5;$o++){
    $my_multiarray[$i][$o]=$o;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This?

```
$my_array = [];  
$my_multiarray = [];

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    $my_array[$i]=$i;

    for($o=0;$o<5;$o++)
        $my_multiarray[$i][$o]=$o;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just gotta add a $ in front of all variables and array handling is exactly the same?

```
<?php
$my_array = []; 
$my_multiarray = [];


for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    $my_array[$i]=$i;

    for($o=0;$o<5;$o++){
        $my_multiarray[$i][$o]=$o;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

it's same in php , just put `$` at the place of `var` , as in javascript `var declares a variable` and `in php $ declares a variable`. You should learn the basics of php by visiting the following link : [PHP BASICS](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

```
$my_array = [];  
$my_multiarray = [];

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    $my_array[$i]=$i;

    for($o=0;$o<5;$o++){
        $my_multiarray[$i][$o]=$o;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code

```
$my_array = array(); 
$my_array2 = array(); 

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

    $my_array[$i] = $i; 

    for($o = 0; $o < 5; $o++)
        $my_array2[$i][$o] = $o;

}
```